# Pruebas Unitarias con TESTNG en Maven

Tags: java, maven, test-ng

Estoy desarrollando pruebas unitarias con  el framework TESTNG y me he encontrado con un problema a la hora de obtener el report de la cobertura.

Pasos:

- Lanzo el proyecto Maven.

  ```
  clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install
  ```
- Finaliza la ejecución pero no se genera el report de la cobertura.
- En la carpeta `Target->coverage-reports` del proyecto se crea el archivo `jacoco-ut.exec`.
- No aparece la cobertura de los test unitarios.

El archivo tiene 80,1KB, pero **no aparece la cobertura reflejada**.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Hola Francisco, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Para poder responder mejor a tu pregunta agradezco añadas a esta la versión de tu JDK y los artefactos de tu proyecto (como el archivo pom.xml) para poder orientarte.